Ubuntu 24.04 with USB-C display
I've been stumped by this for a good couple of days, and as I scoured the stackexchange and other pages, and nothing worked.
The setup is a Samsung Book4, Ubuntu 24.04, and a LG 27U850 display connected via USB-C.
The peripherals, connected to the display, work immediately. On lsusb, I can clearly see:
Bus 003 Device 011: ID 043e:9a39 LG Electronics USA, Inc. 27UP850 - WK.AEUDCSN - External Monitor 4K

The display does not appear under xrandr, nor under Displays or nvidia-settings. I've tried disabling the USB power toggle (in grub), I've tried modifying various BIOS settings. I've ensured the screen works and that the USB works (I can connect it to my macbook and everything works immediately). I've tried commenting out the nvidia-drm modeset under /lib/modprove.d/nvidia-kms.conf and I've also run sudo prime-select nvidia. I also added needs_root_rights=yes to /etc/X11/XWrapper.config, as it was recommended somewhere.
I tried updating displaylink-drivers, NVIDIA drivers (currently 560), etc. Nothing seems to budge this.
What am I missing? This is driving me crazy.
Thanks!
